# Ищу npm - пакет для работы с внешними накопителями(флешки и по.)

Tags: node.js

Здравия всем форумчанам! Прошу помощи.
Существуют ли npm - пакеты , чтобы работать с файлами не только из собственной ФС компьютера, а и из внешних  подключаемых накопителей типа флешек, "карманов" и т.д.?

Comment: Внешние подключаемые накопители абсолютно ничем не отличаются от собственной ФС компьютера. Никакой специальный пакет для этого не нужен.

Comment: Привет, andreymal! При попытке получить имена дисков выдает только имена тех, что на собств. SSD. А флешку не видит.

Comment: Как именно вы пытаетесь получить имена дисков?

Comment: Я ваяю в целях обучения простенький файл - менеджер на связке js/node. Делаю рекурс. обход всех дисков, имена к.рых получаю с пом. npm - пакета, название к.рого сейчас точно не назову(комп не со мной). Что - то вроде diskname... .

Comment: А желательно бы точно назвать, чтобы можно было изучить детали реализации этого пакета и разобраться в странностях его поведения

Comment: К сожалению, только завтра утром буду с компом. Если сможете заглянуть в эту коммент-ленту к обеду, я все вам изложу. Я просто не ожидал настолько оперативной реакции на свой вопрос. Спасибо вам за это.

Comment: Я применял child_process, в котором выполнялась wmic - команда "wmic logicaldisk get Caption/format:list".

Comment: При запуске в командной строке эта команда отобразила у меня абсолютно все буквы диска — даже для неподключенных устройств: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiWJX.png — может, вы сами как-то неправильно обрабатываете результат в nodejs? Или, может, ваше устройство вообще не имеет буквы диска?

Comment: Я скопировал фрагмент кода с чилдпроцессом в другой скрипт, сделал новый сервер, и у меня тоже все отобразилось. Видимо, что - то я накосячил с обработкой, таки да. Спасибо вам!